# Label Google map marker with cookie that holds the verified phone number value

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-maps-markers, firebaseui

This is where I create the cookie to save the verified phone number

```
    'signInSuccess': function(user, credential, redirectUrl) {
    // You can also access this via firebase.auth().currentUser.phoneNumber
    document.cookie =  (firebase.auth().currentUser.phoneNumber);
    handleSignedInUser(user);
    // Do not redirect.
    //'signInSuccessUrl': "http://localhost:8080/CurrentLocation.html",
    return true;
  }
```

This is where I use the cookie value to label a Google map marker

```
var markerLabel = document.cookie;
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: {
      lat: data.User.l[0],
      lng: data.User.l[1]
    },
    map: map,
    label: markerLabel
  });
```

The marker label says

> PhoneNumber=undefined; +1##########

It displays the user's verified number but also says undefined. I only want to display the phone number.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You are not setting the cookie correctly. Lookup a correct way to set/get cookies: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp

In addition, why do you need to use a cookie to save the phone number? Firebase Auth already persists the user. You can get the phone number by calling `firebase.auth().currentUser.phoneNumber` after `onAuthStateChanged` listener is triggered.